# PHP Imagemagick vignette

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, vignette

How want to apply a vignette effect to an image using PHP with ImageMagik.  I found this function but I'm not sure how to use it.

[`Imagick::vignetteImage`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-vignetteimage.php)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please define what you mean by "vignette effect" *exactly*

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer: [read the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.vignetteimage.php).

Comment: The PHP page for [Imagick::vignetteImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.vignetteimage.php) seems to reflect the correct params. Not sure if it was updated after this answer was posted or what, but the param list above is not correct. Here's a relevant discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846665/black-color-of-imagemagick-vignette

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the correct version of Image Magick and the PHP library installed:

```
<?php
    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->readImage($in);
    $image->vignetteImage ( float $blackPoint , float $whitePoint , int $x , int $y )
    $image->writeImage($out);
?>
```